# Get first element from many to many relationship django in template

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to get the first element from queryset which is returned by a Model Field which is a `ManyToManyField` right in the template.

models.py

```
class CraftImage(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='crafts_images/', null=True)


class Craft(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
 images = models.ManyToManyField(CraftImage, blank=True, related_name='craft_images')
```

views.py

```
def work_all(request):
 crafts = Craft.objects.all()
 context = {
  'crafts': crafts,
 }
```

template.py

```
{% for craft in crafts %}

<div style="background-image: url('{{ craft.images[0].image.url }}');"></div>

{% endfor %}
```

Something like this.

I've also tried following some solutions I found which didn't work for me such as..

views.py

```
 crafts = Craft.objects.all()
 images = Craft.objects.values_list('images').first()
 print(images)
 context = {
  'crafts': crafts,
  'images': images
 }
```

templates.py

```
{% for craft in crafts %}

<div style="background-image: url('{% static 'images.image.url' %}');"></div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ craft.images.all.first.image.url }}');"></div>
```